# How to modify slice of queryset persistently without save

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm transforming (highlighting query matches) of a `content` attribute for objects in a search result queryset.  When transforming the attribute during enumeration **over every object** in the queryset **the transformation persists**, at least for the life of the queryset.  For obvious reasons I'm not applying a save, because I only want the transformation to persist for the life of the queryset during the request.

The problem arises when I try to optimize the enumeration to a **slice of the queryset**, then **the transformation no longer (temporarily) persists**.

- Is there way to have transformations persist for a slice too?
- Why are my transformations treated differently for a slice than the full queryset?

A slice of a queryset is still a queryset, although it does not have equivalence 
to the original queryset, even if its a slice of the entire queryset.

- Using Django 1.11.4 and Python 3.6.3

Here's some an example demonstrating the general problem:

```
class Passage(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=256)

Passage.objects.create(content='test 1')
Passage.objects.create(content='test 2')

In [1]: results = Passage.objects.filter(id__lte=2)
In [2]: for result in results:
   ...:     result.content = "hello world"
   ...:
In [3]: [result.content for result in results]
Out[3]: ['hello world', 'hello world']
In [4]: results = Passage.objects.filter(id__lte=2)
In [5]: for result in results[0:2]:
   ...:     result.content = "hello world"
   ...:
In [6]: [result.content for result in results]
Out[6]: ['test 1', 'test 2']
```

Comment: unfortunately i can't to reproduce your problem

Comment: I've updated the example with a real demonstration of it.

Comment: Not able to reproduce the bug.

Comment: You must be doing something different, anyway, the issue is now resolved – you can't do this with a slice, because the original queryset is different than the sliced qs.  If you're able to then you must have either been assigning the slice to a var and enumerating over that or something different than what's described in the issue description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the queryset's slice won't affect the original queryset because the slice is a separate queryset object; the two querysets are lazily evaluated and don't share the model objects in memory. `results` will give you one queryset object, and `results[0:2]` returns a separate queryset object, and when you iterate over the one, the results of the other will not be affected because they are produced at the time you iterate (and cached on the queryset object, which is why your first example works).

Depending on the size of the data, you may be able to get the desired effect by iterating with enumerate:

```
for i, result in enumerate(results):
    if i < 2:
        result.content = 'hello world'
```